# Later.JS - Recur every week, a certain day of the week?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, momentjs, laterjs

I need to make a recurring event using later.js that is weekly, but only repeats on defined days of the week. I.e., it doesn't repeat weekly every day, but only every Tuesday and Friday, for example.

However, later.js seems really inconsistent to me. I've been trying some of the options on their site and some work and others don't.

This example on their site, for example, which is precisely what I need, doesn't work for me:

`later.parse.text('at 5:00 pm on Weds,Thurs and Fri');`

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, it was some kind of error with the later.js file. I deleted the whole later folder that I downloaded with Bower and I re-downloaded later, again using Bower, and now it works.

If yours don't work, try with an online link instead of with a local file. Your file could be old or outdated.

Try this link, this one works: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/later/1.2.0/later.js